# Книги по теме Concurrency и Parallel Programming

Tags: многопоточность, книги, c++

Доброго времени суток!

Посоветуйте книги по теме соответственно. Во многообразии выдачи поисковиков можно потеряться и хочется услышать совета опытных людей, что почитать новичку и разобраться как можно глубже в теме.
Желательно в порядке нарастания сложности для изучения.

Начал пока с этой [C++ Concurrency in Action](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/17636939/)

P.S. на данный момент есть задача: общая очередь заданий, несколько потоков кладут их туда, а несколько читают и соответственно выполняют. В общем, вроде укладывается в паттерн Poducer-Consumer.

Comment: Сам давно хочу изучить параллельное программирование поглубже. Но мне кажется, что для изучения нужна книга не привязанная к какому-то конкретному языку. Примитивы синхронизации везде примерно одинаковые. Как мне кажется важны структуры данных, алгоритмы основанные на этих примитивах и паттерны их использования. Был бы благодарен, если кто-нибудь посоветует такую книжку.

Comment: вот и меня интересует подобная литература.
небольшая подборка ссылок по теме:
http://software.intel.com/ru-ru/articles/parallel/all/1/
http://www.1024cores.net/
http://www.data-race.com/
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/comp.programming.threads
https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/display/ppp/Home

Comment: @Fe1iX, а как Вам книга (C++ Concurrency in Action), которую Вы в вопросе упомянули? 

Я как-то полистал ее в магазине, но не помню уже почему, брать не стал.

Comment: Заказал ее. Обещали к концу недели привезти. Жду пока.

Нашел пару книг интересных ( англ. ):
1. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1737013/Books/Concurrency/the-art-of-concurrency-a-thread-monkeys-guide-to-writing-parallel-applications.pdf
2. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1737013/Books/Concurrency/patterns-for-parallel-programming-software-patterns-series.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В упомянутой книге упор делается на практический аспект многопоточности. Начинать погружение в тему лучше с неё. На ней же можно и закончить. Для большинства реальных задач этого будет достаточно. Если же хочется познать многопоточность на полную глубину и стать мастером, то без изучения теории не обойтись. Для этого есть другая книга - ["Параллельное и распределенное программирование с использованием C++"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1919696/). Описание на [ozon.ru](http://ozon.ru) совершенно не соответствует содержанию. Оно выглядит легкомысленно и ничуть не пугает. Можно подумать, что эта книга для начинающих. В действительности же она представляет собой академический хардкор, читать который очень непросто.

А что касается конкретно паттерна Producer-Consumer, то его реализацию лучше всего делать в lock-free манере. В журнале Dr. Dobb's была [статья о том, как это сделать](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/lock-free-queues/208801974). Правда в вашем случае всё равно потребуется кое-какая блокировка. Нужно будет блокировать отдельно Producer'ов и отдельно Consumer'ов, чтобы в очередь одновременно не лезло более одного потока каждого вида.

Comment: Да, весьма крутая книга. Но очень хорошая.

Answer (score 1):

Ну насчет параллельности не знаю, а вот по concurrency есть такой гуру [Doug Lea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doug_Lea). По ссылке есть его книжки. Видел даже его сайт с исходниками/примерами и проч.

Answer (score 0):

[[@Fe1iX](/users/4410/fe1ix)](/users/4410/fe1ix), что лучше читать, не знаю.

А для задачи, не заморачивайтесь, делайте попроще.

Если в *nix, то для разделения доступа используйте `pthread_mutex_t` (`pthread_mutex_lock()/pthread_mutex_unlock()` из pthread.h), а для управления очередью `sem_t` (`sem_wait()/sem_post()` из semaphore.h).

Comment: В принципе первоначальная реализация так и сделана. Но хочется лучше разобраться в теме.

Comment: @Fe1iX, все что попадалось в последнее время - это либо пережевывание очевидного, либо некие теоретические заморочки. 

Можно поискать исходники в сети. Помнится как-то видел красивые, но не помню где.