# Методы оптимизации, основанные на эффективном использовании оборудования

Tags: алгоритм, оптимизация

А давайте соберём здесь неалгоритмические методы оптимизации программ. Не алгоритмы «N*log n вместо N^2», а приёмы позволяющие использовать имеющееся оборудование более эффективно. Что приходит на ум мне:

**Использование кэша процессора**:

- Обработка данных небольшими порциями, чтобы каждый раз все необходимые данные влезали в кэш. 
  ***Пример*** (для начала; можно придумать что-то более удачное): для quicksort эта рекомендация выполняется, когда дело доходит до небольших блоков. Но на больших объёмах данных на первых итерациях сортируемые и сливаемые половинки не помещаются в кэш. Следствие: если, допустим, помимо сортировки надо с данными сделать что-то ещё, это выгодно делать после сортировки каждого небольшого блока, пока данные ещё в кэше.

**Обход латентности доступа к данным** (применимо и к чтению/записи данных процессором из памяти и к работе с диском):

- Чтение/запись данных последовательно, а не в случайном порядке. ***Пример:*** внешняя сортировка позволяет обойтись эффективными операциями чтения/записи больших последовательных блоков данных. Если реализовать quicksort с хранением данных на диске, то при объёме данных > объёма кэша потребуется O(n * log n) движений головки диска.
- Буферизация ввода/вывода. ***Пример:*** всё та же внешняя сортировка. Одна из операций там – слияние данных из нескольких файлов с диска и запись результата на диск. Это будет работать гораздо быстрее, если читать данные из каждого входного файла порциями, скажем, по 10 МБ и писать результаты в буфер, который сбрасывать на диск тоже по мере накопления.
- Группировка нужных данных. ***Пример:*** параллельные массивы. Допустим, у нас есть большой массив точек на плоскости и описание к каждой из них длиной 50 символов. Тогда, например, выбор точек, попадающих в некоторый прямоугольник (допустим, нам невыгодно применять что-то более сложное, чем простой проход по массиву) будет работать существенно быстрее, если разбить информацию на два массива:

  struct THeader {  int x, y;  };
  struct TInfo {  char description[50];  };
  THeader dotHeaders[10000000], dotInfos[10000000];

  [Другой похожий пример (вопрос Примеры оптимизации путём группировки данных в памяти)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/268173/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8).

**Оптимальное использование имеющейся пропускной способности**:

- Сжатие данных «на лету». ***Пример:*** объёмная база данных с некоторыми  закономерностями в данных (между полями записей или между соседними записями). Сжатие данных перед записью на диск и расжатие при чтении может позволить достичь большей скорости записи/чтения с диска.
- Использование специальных команд процессора, содержащих дополнительные "подсказки" по работе с памятью. ***Пример:*** intrinsic'и _mm_stream_ps и т.п. в примере http://pastebin.com/Xzq9dYww @superhackkiller1997'a. _mm_stream_ps компилируется в команду [MOVNTPS](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc197.htm) - аналог memset, работающий в обход кэша.

**Обход «неудобных» шаблонов доступа к данным**:

- Выравнивание данных по границам, кратным 4, 8 и более байт. Обычно делается компилятором именно потому, что на многих процессорах доступ, например, к 4-байтному целому в памяти по адресу, не кратному 4, намного медленнее.

**Использование нескольких имеющихся устройств одновременно** (несколько ядер процессора/несколько вычислительных устройств в ядре процессора/процессор и диск):

- Многопоточная обработка. Эта тема слишком обширная чтобы пытаться охватить её здесь.
- Использование специальных наборов команд процессора (MMX, SSE, …).
- Расчёты на графических картах.
- Обработка данных в одном потоке, буферизация и сохранение в другом потоке.

**Обход латентности конвейера процессора**:

- Уменьшение количества условных переходов в принципе.
- В частности – путём разворачивания циклов. ***Пример:*** для несложной обработки большого массива данных

вместо

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
  process(a[i]);
```

может быть выгодно написать

```
int i, stopI = n - 4;
for (i = 0; i <= stopI; i += 4) {
  process(a[i]);
  process(a[i + 1]);
  process(a[i + 2]);
  process(a[i + 3]);
}
for ( ; i < n; i++) 
  process(a[i]);
```

(естественно, очень желательно, чтобы функции process была inline или просто одним оператором)

- Переупорядочивание операций. Подходит и для уменьшения зависимостей по данным и для загрузки большего количества вычислительных устройств.
- Совмещение итераций цикла. Аналогично предыдущему пункту – подходит для разных случаев. ***Пример*** (тут тоже можно придумать что-нибудь получше): для обработки большого массива данных

вместо

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  b[i].x += deltaX;
  if (b[i].x < 0)
    b[i].x += 100;
  b[i].y *= b[i].x * y2;
}
```

-

```
int i, stopI = n - 2;
for (i = 0; i <= stopI; i += 2) {
  b[i].x += deltaX;
  if (b[i].x < 0)
    b[i].x += 100;
  b[i + 1].x += deltaX;   // Пока  b[i].y *= b[i].x * y2; ждёт выполнения процессором условия и, возможно, += 100, мы начинаем обрабатывать следующий элемент
  if (b[i + 1].x < 0)
    b[i + 1].x += 100;
  b[i].y *= b[i].x * y2;
  b[i + 1].y *= b[i + 1].x * y2;
}
for ( ; i < n; i++) 
  …
```

Comment: На мой взгляд и опыт, самый общий рецепт тут - использование параллелизма, особенно на GPU.

Comment: А я бы наоборот, если бы надо было выбрать один приём, назвал обеспечение последовательного доступа к данным

Comment: Одно другому не мешает. И потом, эффективное программирование GPU - та еще забава. Там тоже нужно думать о правильном обращении к памяти, о пересылках данных, о кеше и пр. При этом можно получить ускорение на современных GPU в сотни раз.

Comment: По формату топик, скорее, напоминает исследование. Вопрос к модераторам: Может стоит преобразовать?

Comment: Ок, попробую что-нибудь вспомнить/изобрести. Пример "обхода латентности конвейера процессора" путём перемешивания операций сам хотел бы посмотреть. Однажды пробовал - эффекта не добился.



Upd: добавил пример к "группировке нужных данных"


Ссылок не дам, т.к. я базируюсь, в основном, на своих знаниях архитектуры, почерпнутых отовсюду, каких-то случаях из жизни и на рассказах коллег (типа "как я ускорил поворот матрицы, которая не помещалась в оперативную память")

Comment: @Risto, в принципе Вы наверное правы, но IMHO как только тема попадает в *"Исследования"* интерес к ней (активность обсуждения) резко падает (остается 2-3 человека). Более того, здесь можно активно отвечать, а в формате исследований нет (а размер комментариев там тоже ограничен (как и здесь)).

А тема  в принципе интересная, может кто-то что дельное скажет.

IMHO лучше оставить здесь.

--

@Михаил М, не очень-то мне вериться в эффективность ручного перемешивания операций. Хороший компилятор с оптимизатором, скажем icc для процессоров Intel наверняка справится с этим лучше.

Answer (score 6):

Хорошая идея! Подождём ответов от специалистов по оптимизациям.

Внесу свои 5 копеек: битовые трюки. Многие операции имеют неожиданно простую и эффективную реализацию с учётом особенностей двоичной записи чисел. Вот [популярный сборник](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Пример: для *положительного* числа `v` выражение

```
(v & (v - 1)) == 0
```

определяет, является ли `v` степенью двойки.

Ещё одним классическим трюком на грани между алгоритмическими и неалгоритмическими является быстрое вычисление [`1/sqrt(x)`](http://www.beyond3d.com/content/articles/8/) из Quake.

Comment: Врут ведь

    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/codegoogle/smhasher$ gcc -O3 t.c -lm
    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/codegoogle/smhasher$ time ./a.out 
    sqrt() -lm : x = 65536.000000
    
    real 0m9.956s
    user 0m9.057s
    sys  0m0.168s
    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/codegoogle/smhasher$ gcc -O3 -DQUAKE t.c -lm
    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/codegoogle/smhasher$ time ./a.out 
    QUAKE: x = 65536.003900
    
    real 0m13.387s
    user 0m12.201s
    sys  0m0.232s
    avp@avp-xub11:~/src/codegoogle/smhasher$ 

и вообще, эта 1/sqrt наверное для CPU без "аппаратного" sqrt.

Comment: @avp: А исходник выложите? А вообще-то, все неалгоритмические трюки очень системно-, компиляторо-, оптимизаторо- и процессорозависимые, так что всегда надо пробовать перед использованием и не завязывать архитектуру на них.

Comment: Сейчас выложу. В комментарий не лезет.

Comment: На SO пишут, что начиная с SSE есть такая инструкция, rsqrtss. И *этот алгоритм был разработан, когда Pentium был топовым процессором. Она не эффективна на современных процессорах: чтение 8-ми байт сразу после записи их двумя 4-байтными порциями очень медленно (погуглите "store forwarding stalls")* [carmack's invsqrt in asm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12027540/carmacks-invsqrt-in-asm)

Answer (score 5):

Внесу свои пять копеек. В многопоточных программах могут возникнуть проблемы с производительностью, когда потоки интенсивно выделяют/освобождают память. Это происходит из-за того, что стандартный malloc не умеет работать параллельно и просто делает lock на каждое выделение. С этим можно бороться по-разному, например выделяя большой кусок памяти для каждого потока, и используя его как пул. Но самый простой способ, это применить библиотеку tcmalloc, которая входит в [gperttools](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/). Самое приятное, что для ее использования ничего не надо менять в исходниках, нужно просто добавить флаг `-ltcmalloc` при линковке. На моей памяти простое добавление tcmalloc увеличивало производительность на 20-30% в одном проекте, связанном с алгоритмами на графе.

**UPD**: Наваял демонстрацию:

```
$ cat test.cc
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  const int THREADS = 2;
  const int ITERATIONS = 50000000;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  std::vector<int> arr(THREADS, 0);
  for (int t = 0; t < THREADS; ++t) {
    threads.emplace_back([t, &arr]() {
      for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {
        std::unique_ptr<int> ptr1(new int(i));
        std::unique_ptr<double> ptr2(new double(i));
        arr[t] += *ptr1 + *ptr2;
        arr[t] %= ITERATIONS;
      }
    });
  }
  for (std::thread& thread: threads) {
    thread.join();
  }
  int sum = 0;
  for (int s: arr) {
    sum = (sum + s) % ITERATIONS;
  }
  return sum;
}
$ g++-4.7 --std=c++11 test.cc -O2 -pthread
$ time ./a.out

real    0m16.127s
user    0m30.602s
sys 0m0.172s
$ g++-4.7 --std=c++11 test.cc -O2 -pthread -ltcmalloc
$ time ./a.out

real    0m8.743s
user    0m16.417s
sys 0m0.056s
```

Как видно, даже на 2-х тредах tcmalloc ускорил программу почти в 2 раза.

Answer (score 3):

Вот такой примитвный. Просто транслирую с -DQUAKE и запускаю через time.

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/codegoogle/smhasher$ grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo 
model name  : Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5400  @ 2.70GHz
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/codegoogle/smhasher$

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//float InvSqrt (float x);
static inline float InvSqrt (float x){
    float xhalf = 0.5f*x;
    int i = *(int*)&x;
    i = 0x5f3759df - (i>>1);
    x = *(float*)&i;
    x = x*(1.5f - xhalf*x*x);
    return x;
}

#if QUAKE
#define WHO "QUAKE"
#else
#define WHO "sqrt() -lm "
#endif

int main()
{
  int i;
  float x = 1.0;

  for (i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
#if QUAKE
    x += InvSqrt(x);
#else
  x += 1 / sqrt(x);
#endif

  printf ("%s: x = %f\n", WHO, x);
}
```

Comment: Круто. Это прекрасно подтверждает тезис о том, что преждевременная оптимизация — источник всех бед.

Comment: @avp: Хм. Поменфл стартовую константу на 1.1 и уменьшил в 10 раз количество итераций:

    [Vlad@Kenga] [17:02:24] [~/c++]
    {0,514}$> gcc -O3 quakesqrt.cpp -o quakesqrt -lm && time ./quakesqrt
    sqrt() -lm : x = 65536.000000

    real    0m3.205s
    user    0m3.125s
    sys     0m0.046s

    [Vlad@Kenga] [17:02:40] [~/c++]
    {0,515}$> gcc -O3 -DQUAKE quakesqrt.cpp -o quakesqrt -lm && time ./quakesqrt
    QUAKE: x = 282124.157738

    real    0m1.188s
    user    0m1.140s
    sys     0m0.015s

Comment: Не, этот код слишком маленький и не запутанный :) (ядрёная формула не в счёт!). Он скорее подтверждает компиляторо- и процессорозависимость. 
Мда, опасно так (x += 1 / sqrt(x)) играть. Операция деления вон тоже довольно быстрая, если делитель оказывается степенью двойки

Comment: Еще на одном компе посмотрел (также поменял начальное значение на 1.1)

    [avp@nas ~]$ gcc -O3 qt.c -lm
    [avp@nas ~]$ time ./a.out
    sqrt() -lm : x = 65536.000000
    
    real 0m1.925s
    user 0m1.925s
    sys 0m0.000s
    [avp@nas ~]$ gcc -DQUAKE -O3 qt.c 
    [avp@nas ~]$ time ./a.out
    QUAKE: x = 65536.000000
    
    real 0m2.029s
    user 0m2.028s
    sys 0m0.001s
    [avp@nas ~]$ grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo | tail -1
    model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5520  @ 2.27GHz
    [avp@nas ~]$ 
    
и опять родной sqrt быстрее

Comment: @avp: у вас процессор круче.

    [Vlad@Kenga] [20:12:15] [~/t]
    {0,538}$> grep 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo
    model name      : Dual Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 175
    model name      : Dual Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 175

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению, у нас начинается флейм оптимизаторов-теоретиков и оптимизаторов-практиков (здесь и в [вопросе-примере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/268173/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8)). Но т.к. я вспомнил практический пример в тему, я его всё-таки приведу :) . К вопросу о том, что всё, что не даёт лучшей оценки (O(n*log n) вместо O(n^2) и т.п.)- это баловство.

Я тоже как-то, например, написал для каждой вставки в базу дополнительный select max(id)+1 ... Авто-инкремент там нельзя было сделать т.к. несколько процессов заливали данные в одну таблицу, но каждый - в своём диапазоне id, чтобы можно было по этим id в каждом диапазоне находить новые данные. Но суть не в этом.

Суть в том, что когда код заработал, производительность была довольно грустной. Точно не помню, приведу очень примерные цифры ради отображения соотношений величин. Допустим, записывалось 50 элементов данных в секунду. При этом в процессе работы всех загрузчиков новых данных поступает 10 в секунду. Но когда загрузчики перезапускаются, им в сумме нужно загрузить 20000 элементов. Т.е. запас по прочности вроде как в 5 раз, но при рестарте надо ждать 6 минут. А код надо ещё тестировать и отлаживать.

Было понятно, что select max(id)+1 это хрень, но избавление от него обещало прирост ну процентов 20 (что такого, быстренько в индексе пробежаться, тем более, он и так в памяти). И я точно помню, что мне казалось, что смысла нет. Тем не менее, после того, как мы немного подумали и я поправил эту и несколько подобных мелких проблем, производительность возросла раза в 3. И просто работать стало намного приятней! Не говоря о том, что я сэкономил себе много часов ожидания на имеющихся машинах (вполне нормальных по тем временам). Т.е. можно было ходить и плакаться, что мне надо машину на 1000$ дороже и сервер тоже, а можно было подумать-поработать пару дней.

**Upd:** нашёл в одном вопросе ([Книги по теме Concurrency и Parallel Programming](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/136119/c-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-concurrency-%D0%B8-parallel-programming)) замечательный сборник статей. И в частности: приём переделки бинарных деревьев с тем, чтобы при спуске по дереву приходилось читать из памяти менее разбросанные данные: [1024CORES / RAM - не RAM, или Cache-Conscious Data Structures](http://www.1024cores.net/home/in-russian/ram---ne-ram-ili-cache-conscious-data-structures). Читается легко, всем рекомендую :)

Comment: Вообще-то, тысяча баксов — зарплата хорошего программиста за 2-3 дня. Поэтому возможно «купить сервер получше» является более выгодной стратегий в краткосрочной перспективе.

Comment: В среднестатистической России, 10000 баксов в месяц? И, к слову, я тогда был скорее junior'ом

Comment: @Михаил М: в среднестатистической Германии. Учите язык и уезжайте.