# Опять об оптимизации. gcc -O3 Intel i5-2500 Segmentation fault

Tags: gcc, оптимизация, intel

Это скорее сообщение, навеянное темами [Методы оптимизации, основанные на эффективном использовании оборудования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/267750) и [Примеры оптимизации путём группировки данных в памяти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/268173), чем вопрос. Надеюсь, что для кому-нибудь оно окажется полезным.

Недавно подбирал с помощью [SMHasher](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/) подходящую для реализации хэш-таблиц в одной конкретной задаче хэш-функцию.  Заметил, что на скорость поиска в таблице с длинными (несколько десятков байт) ключами в основном влияет именно скорость работы функции, вычисляющей хэш-код (число), а не "качество" хэш-кода.

Известно, что в X-86 и X-64 допустимо обращение к невыровненным целым числам. Поэтому я попробовал вот такую примитивную функцию (стиль для запуска в SMHasher):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void 
dummyhash (const void *key, int len, uint32_t seed, void *out)
{
  uint32_t h = seed, *pk = (uint32_t *)key;

  for (; len > 3; len -= 4, pk++)
    h ^= (*pk + len);

  const u_char *s = (u_char *)pk;
  switch (len) {
  case 3:
    h ^= ((*s++ + 3) << 24);
  case 2:
    h ^= ((*s++ + 2) << 16);
  case 1:
    h ^= (*s + 1);
  }

  *(uint32_t*)out = h;
}
```

И действительно, результаты оказались самыми лучшими. Однако, если оттранслировать ее **gcc -O3** компилятор GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, то на

```
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
```

для невыровненных на границу 4 байта ключах, длиннее 15 байт программа **падает с Segmentation Fault**, но на CPU

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5520  @ 2.27GHz
```

**ОНА ЖЕ работает нормально** (именно исполнимый файл, полученный на i5 и падающий там(!)), ну, на машинах с X-86 тоже все работает (естественно собранное для X-86).

(Если вдруг кому-то интересен ассемблерный код, то я его [выложил сюда](http://pastebin.com/8KyJCK1E).)

Такое, вот, любопытное наблюдение.

Кстати, а под конец все-таки вопрос: *как вы считаете, где на самом деле ошибка в GNU или в Intel?*

**Update**, вызывающий код.

t.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>


void dummyhash(const void *, int, uint32_t, void *);

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char t[256], res[16];
  memset(t, 0, 256);

  printf ("Hi, i am %ld bit\n", (long)sizeof(long) * 8);

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 3) {
    printf("%p  %d ", t+i, i); fflush(stdout);
    dummyhash((void *)(t + i), 32, 0, (void *)res);
  }

  puts("end");

}
```

Еще раз повторюсь, работает **gcc -O2 -c dummyhash.c** на Xeon и i5-2500.

C **gcc -O3** работает на Xeon, а на i5-2500 валится по **Segmentation Fault**.

Один и тот же *загрузочный модуль*, созданный на i5-2500.

То что данные не выровнены на границу слова, я естественно знаю, по идее это все равно должно работать (медленнее, но это к делу не относится) в X-64.

---

**Update 2**

Ответ и комментарии @user1034749 побудили меня все же вернуться к этому хламу и модифицировать код так, чтобы он работал независимо от выравнивания данных на разных CPU (в т.ч. требующих выравнивания для типа int).

Сразу скажу, что сделать *тот же самый алгоритм* (конкретно, такое же использование длины ключа при вычислении хэша как в коде выше) без копирования данных **мне не удалось (кто сможет, пишите ответы!!!)**.

Понятно, что копирование в выровненную область напрочь убивает производительность подобных функций, поэтому я просто отказался от сложения очередной 4-ки байт ключа с оставшейся его длиной при вычислениях хэша. И тут снова неожиданное открытие. Оказалось, что даже при компиляции с -msse2 -O3 (которая вызывала падение на i5 и x-86) программа *на невыровненных данных* валиться перестала. Т.е. к падению приводила не собственно загрузка невыровненных int в xmm-регистр, а последующая команда сложения (что-то с конвейером в этих моделях? (в общем, конечно, вопросы к Intel остаются...)).

Впрочем, наверное хватит слов. Для интересующихся код. Естественно, качество хэш-функции по сравнению с первым вариантом упало.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define ROTL32(v,n) (((uint32_t)(v) << (n)) | ((uint32_t)(v) >> (32 - (n))))

void
dummyhash (const void *key, int keylen, uint32_t seed, void *out)
{
  uint32_t h = 0, h1 = 0, 
    *pkey, len = keylen > 0 ? keylen : 0, 
    i = 0, 
    bnd = __alignof__(h), ofs = ((long)key & (bnd - 1));
  u_char *ph1 = (u_char *)&h1, 
    *s = (u_char *)key;


  if (ofs && len > sizeof(*pkey) - 1)
    for (; i < bnd - ofs; i++, len--)
      ph1[i] = *s++;

  for (pkey = (uint32_t *)s; 
       len > sizeof(*pkey) - 1; len -= sizeof(*pkey), pkey++)
    h ^= *pkey;
  h = ROTL32(h, (bnd - ofs) * CHAR_BIT);

  for (s = (u_char *)pkey; len; len--, i++)
    ph1[i % sizeof(h1)] ^= *s++;

  *(uint32_t*)out = h ^ h1 ^ seed;
}
```

Comment: Хм. Мне кажется, у вас вот здесь: `pk = (uint32_t *)key` нарушение strict aliasing rule, а значит, технически это UB.

Как именно это UB сработало? Например, так: имея указатель на `uint32_t`, компилятор вправе считать (пользуясь strict aliasing rule), что этот `uint32_t` он выделил сам, а значит, что его выравнивание такое, какое хочется компилятору, а не такое, как фактически выходит.

Disclaimer: я не читал и не анализировал ассемблерный код.

Comment: Так именно что невыровненный доступ разрешён на X86. Дело не в выравнивании. Где-то наверняка какая-то ошибка в логике, возможно, там, где эта функция вызывается. Падает-то при доступе к какому адресу?



... О-ё-ё, а где операторы подписаны в ассемблерном коде?... Но, похоже, используется SSE, может действительно оптимизатор ошибочно выбрал выровненную операцию

Comment: @VladD, @Михаил М, попробовал, но ничего от  -fno-strict-aliasing и -fstrict-aliasing не изменилось.

Но, вопросик-то про другое. *Как Intel и GNU дошли до такой жизни, что код на одном из процессоров архитектуры X-64 выполняется (на xeon), а на другом (i5) тот же код падает?*.

Вообще же gcc -O3 надо использовать с осторожностью, недаром Linux компилируют с -O2.

@Михаил М, если интересно, то вызывающий код положил в **update** темы.

Comment: @avp: а можно попросить компилятор вставлять соответствующую строчку сишного кода как комментарий в ассемблер? И ещё, на какой _ассемблерной_ инструкции валится код?

Comment: @avp, очень интересно :) . 



Да, уже больше похоже на баг компилятора. Я довольно много встречал в gcc - передача double и int64 в функции при включённой оптимизации, переменные не изменяются через приведение указателей...



>код на одном из процессоров архитектуры X-64 выполняется (на xeon), а на другом (i5) тот же код падает



Ну подумаешь, у нас один баг только на Windows 2003 проявлялся, причём стабильно. Типа, только там в структуре при освобождении оказывалось значение 5, по совместительству VT_BSTR :)

Comment: SSE-инструкция обращается к невыровненным данным, думаю причина в этом. То что после пересборки под другую архитектуру работает - другой код и/или выравнивание.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, то что SSE к невыровненным -- это очевидно. Только вот на Xeon работает, а на I5 -- нет. Про пересборки -- почитайте *все внимательно*. Апофеоз же в том, что ---  **Один и тот же загрузочный модуль, созданный на i5-2500** работает на Xeon и валится на I5. Правда, сам я *глубоко* в спецификации этих камней не вникал, на первый взгляд про  работоспособность SSE с невыровненными данными ничего нет. / Ежели что конкретное нароете -- отпишитесь.

Comment: А, я прочитал что пересобрали исполняемый файл... Данные по family/model/stepping сможете для двух камней привести? Попробую порыться.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, по I5 -- `vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 42
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
stepping        : 7
cpu MHz         : 3252.096
cache size      : 6144 KB
` (остальные CPU такие же), а машинки с тем Xeon под рукой нет, но надо думать, что `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5520  @ 2.27GHz` это о ней (family/model/stepping кто знает? наверное самые обычные для 2-х лет назад)

Answer (score 3):

> Кстати, а под конец все-таки вопрос: как вы считаете, где на самом деле ошибка в GNU >или в Intel?

Ошибка в вашем коде. В стандарте C есть упоминание
"memory align requirements". "Сколько именно в байтах"
отдано на откуп компилятору.

> То что данные не выровнены на границу слова, я естественно знаю, по идее это все >равно должно работать (медленнее, но это к делу не относится) в X-64.

Компилятор может предъявлять более строгие требования,
чем процессор (и ABI на платформу), это никак стандарту не противоречит.
И gcc как раз предъявляет, на amd64 скомпилируйте и запустите
такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%u\n", (unsigned)__alignof__(int32_t));
}
```

и вы узнаете, что требования по выравниванию 4.
И компилятор расчитывает, что вы соблюдаете эти требования,
а если нет то он будет генерировать код который может падать,
а может не падать и работать нормально, в общем корректная
работа gcc гарантируется, только если вы соблюдаете требования
по выравниваю.

Comment: читайте вопросы **внимательно**. Его суть в том, почему на I5 и Xeon (оба, как известно, X64) код, откомпилированный с -O3 (с -O2 все OK и тут и там) работает по разному (следовательно, где причина ошибки -- Intel (SSE на I5 *с данными длиннее 16 байт!!!* неожиданно требует выравнивания) или GNU).

Comment: Могу переформулировать: gcc в своём праве, он генерирует ассемблер из предположения, что int32_t* имеет выравнивается 4, если вы хотите выбирать из двух вариантов, то мой ответ один из ваших двух вариантов убирает. Но первопричина в плохом коде а не процессоре или компиляторе

Comment: Ну, то что код не кроссплатформенный это мне известно с самого начала и указано в вопросе. Естественно, он только для процессоров, которые могут работать с невыровненными данными (как мне *казалось* это все х-86). / Действительно, gcc `__alignof__` на I5 == 4 (для Xeon посмотреть сейчас не могу, но подозреваю тот же ответ). И понятно, что GNU с себя этим всю ответственность снимает :). / Только вот нигде не могу найти (нагуглить, если честно) упоминаний о таком различии в поведении I5(SandyBridge) и Xeon по отношению к SSE (только упоминания о различии в производительности встречаются).

Comment: >"то что код не кроссплатформенный" здесь понятие кроссплатформенный и платформозависимый не применима ИМХО, т.к. код может падать почти везде, например на 32битном CPU, если собрать с флагом типа "-msse2", т.к. современный gcc и для 32 битных x86 требует 4 байтого выравнивания uint32_t.

Comment: Все же подвинули Вы меня к изменению кода... (см. Update 2, если интересно) (ну, на самом деле, все же на практике все это актуально только для CPU, которым **действительно** нужно выравнивание при доступе к int)

Comment: А всем современным нужно, они же тормозят от доступа по не выровненному адресу.

Comment: Тоже верно, процентов на 10 (мерял на Dual-Core  CPU      E5400  @ 2.70GHz и Xeon(R) CPU           E5520  @ 2.27GHz (если интересно, Xeon оказался быстрее в 3 раза, но IMHO память у этих машинок существенно разная))